# Does Xcode include miscellaneous files in the project folder when building

Tags: ios, xcode, file

I keep some miscellaneous files in the folder for my project, files not actually involved in the build. I was wondering, however, wether Xcode will include these in the build. I need to make sure these files aren't taking up space and slowing down builds. Do these files have any effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode will only include files that have been added to the projects copy bundle resources build phase.

You can see these files by selecting your project ,  click on the target , the select the build phases tab,  and click on the Copy Bundle Resources.